# Why does this Fortran module interface give different results depending on how many of its functions are used?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, generic-programming, allocatable-array

I have written a module that contains a interface called 'push' that pushes values onto allocatable arrays. I want it to have generic behavior so that I can add a new function for a given type to the 'push' interface as needed. The problem is that as the amount of functions for a given interface grows, so does the strange behavior of the push interface.

Code for the module (push_array.f90):

```
module push_array
  implicit none
  ! usage:
  ! array = push(array,val)
  interface push
     module procedure push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int
     module procedure push_scalar_int2_onto_rank1_int2
     module procedure push_rank1_int_onto_rank2_int
     module procedure push_rank1_real8_onto_rank2_real8
  end interface push

contains
  function push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int (array,val) result (new_array)
    integer,intent(in),allocatable :: array(:)
    integer,intent(in) :: val
    integer,allocatable :: new_array(:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(size(array) + 1))
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(:) = array(:)
    new_array(length) = val
    return
  end function push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int

  function push_scalar_int2_onto_rank1_int2 (array,val) result (new_array)
    integer(2),intent(in),allocatable :: array(:)
    integer(2),intent(in) :: val
    integer(2),allocatable :: new_array(:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(size(array) + 1))
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(:) = array(:)
    new_array(length) = val
    return
  end function push_scalar_int2_onto_rank1_int2

  function push_rank1_int_onto_rank2_int (array,val) result (new_array)
    integer,intent(in),allocatable :: array(:,:)
    integer,intent(in) :: val(:)
    integer,allocatable :: new_array(:,:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array,2) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(1:size(val),length))
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(1:size(val),:) = array(1:size(val),:)
    new_array(1:size(val),length) = val
    return
  end function push_rank1_int_onto_rank2_int

    function push_rank1_real8_onto_rank2_real8 (array,val) result (new_array)
    real(8),intent(in),allocatable :: array(:,:)
    real(8),intent(in) :: val(:)
    real(8),allocatable :: new_array(:,:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array,2) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(1:size(val),length))
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(1:size(val),:) = array(1:size(val),:)
    new_array(1:size(val),length) = val
    return
  end function push_rank1_real8_onto_rank2_real8

end module push_array
```

Test code (test_push_array.f90):

```
program main
  use push_array, only: push
  implicit none
  integer,allocatable :: a(:)
  integer(2),allocatable :: b(:)
  integer,allocatable :: c(:,:)
  real(8),allocatable :: d(:,:)
  integer :: xp(3)
  real(8) :: xp8(3)
  integer :: i
  integer(2) :: j
  ! test that a scalar integer can be pushed onto a rank1 integer array
  do i=1,100
     a = push(a,i)
  end do
  print *, a(1),a(100)

  ! test that a scalar integer(2) can be pushed onto a rank1 integer(2) array
  do j=1,100
     b = push(b,j)
  end do
  print *, b(1),b(100)

  ! test that a rank1 integer can be pushed onto a rank2 integer
  do i=1,100
     xp = [i,i+1,i+2]
     c = push(c,xp)
  end do
  print *, c(1:3,1),c(1:3,100)

  ! test that a rank1 real(8) can be pushed onto a rank2 real(8)
  do i=1,100
     xp8 = [i + 0.001,i + 0.002, i + 0.003]
     d = push(d,xp8)
  end do
  print *, d(:,1),d(:,100)

end program main
```

make output to show compiler flags:

```
$ make
gfortran -g -O2 -c push_array.f90
gfortran -g -O2 -o main test_push_array.f90 push_array.o
```

My compiler version:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My system:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin darthan 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

If I run the test code with as given, it goes into an infinite loop and my system memory is completely exhausted. I tried to trace the test case in gdb by setting breakpoint where I push i onto a in the first loop,but gdb is unable to step into the module function.

If I comment just the first test loop where i is pushed onto a, here are the results:

```
$ ./main
      1    100
           1           2           3         100         101         102
   1.0010000467300415        1.0019999742507935        1.0030000209808350        100.00099945068359        100.00199890136719        100.00299835205078
```

These would be expected.

If I comment out just the second loop where I push j onto b, here are the results:

```
$ ./main
           1         100
           1           2           3         100         101         102
   1.0010000467300415        1.0019999742507935        1.0030000209808350        100.00099945068359        100.00199890136719        100.00299835205078
```

Once again, as expected.

Things start getting strange when I comment out just the third loop where I push xp onto c:

```
$ ./main
           1           0
      1      0
   1.0010000467300415        1.0019999742507935        1.0030000209808350        100.00099945068359        100.00199890136719        100.00299835205078
```

The pattern continues when I comment out just the fourth loop where I push xp8 onto d:

```
$ ./main
           1           0
      1      0
           1           2           3         100         101         102
```

My questions:

1. Why does the main test program go into a infinite loop when I try to use all four functions defined in the push interface in the same program?
2. In the case where I comment out the third and fourth loops , why do the results for a(100) and b(100) both equal to 0?

Any feedback would be appreciated...thanks!

Edit:

The two functions that needed to be changed are given below

```
  function push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int (array,val) result (new_array)
    integer,intent(in),allocatable :: array(:)
    integer,intent(in) :: val
    integer,allocatable :: new_array(:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(length)) ! changed
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(:) = array(:)
    new_array(length) = val
    return
  end function push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int

  function push_scalar_int2_onto_rank1_int2 (array,val) result (new_array)
    integer(2),intent(in),allocatable :: array(:)
    integer(2),intent(in) :: val
    integer(2),allocatable :: new_array(:)
    integer :: length
    if (allocated(array)) then
       length = size(array) + 1
    else
       length = 1
    end if
    allocate(new_array(length)) ! changed
    if (allocated(array)) new_array(:) = array(:)
    new_array(length) = val
    return
  end function push_scalar_int2_onto_rank1_int2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate statement in some of the function bodies references the size of the `array` argument.  If the `array` argument is not allocated, that reference is invalid.

Earlier in the procedure you test for allocation status and set a variable named `length` - perhaps you meant to use that.

(For clarity - perhaps look at the allocate statement in the `push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int` function.)

Comment: If I print whether or not the returned array "a" is allocated in the loop in the main program for gfortran it returns true and ifort returns false.

Comment: The problem is the initial allocation status of `a` - by the time the function returns in the first iteration of the loop things have already gone bad.

Answer (score 1):

IanH explains the problem.  The compiler can help you find it.  I get different responses from gfortran 4.8 depending on the compilation options.  With `-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace` it compiles, then gives runtime error:

```
At line 25 of file push.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'new_array' above upper bound of -265221874
```

line 25 is the line before `return` in `push_scalar_int_onto_rank1_int`.

Comment: Oddly, I didn't get any error message at runtime using those flags, still just hangs. Would have been nice if it had thrown it!